# The name 'queen' does not exist in the current context- How do I attach the Box to the data?

Tags: c#, button, design-view

new to Windows Forms.  I can't get rid of this error and I believe it's because I don't have button_1 linked to my Queen class and/or my instance 'queen.'  If that's the case, how do I do that in the button's properties on design view in VS?  Here's some of the pertinent code:

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Worker[] workers = new Worker[4];
            workers[0] = new Worker(new string[] { "Nectar collector", "Honey manufacturing" });
            workers[1] = new Worker(new string[] { "Egg care", "Baby bee tutoring" });
            workers[2] = new Worker(new string[] { "Hive maintenance", "Sting patrol" });
            workers[3] = new Worker(new string[] { "Nectar collector", "Honey manufacturing", "Egg care",
                "Baby bee tutoring", "Hive maintenance", "Sting patrol" });
            Queen queen = new Queen(workers);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (queen.AssignWork(workerBeeJob.Text, (int)shifts.Value) == false)
            MessageBox.Show("No workers are available to do the job '" + workerBeeJob.Text +
                ".' The queen bee says...");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("The job '" + workerBeeJob.Text + "' will be done in " 
                    + shifts.Value + " shifts.  The queen bee says...");
        }


class Queen
    {
        private Worker[] workers;
        private int shiftNumber = 0;

        public Queen(Worker[] workers)
        {
            this.workers = workers;
        }

        public bool AssignWork(string job, int numberOfShifts)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < workers.Length; i++)
                if (workers[i].DoThisJob(job, numberOfShifts))
                    return true;
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the scope of the variable. Your form does not have a member called *queen* on it (the one you created in the constructor does not belong to the form), so the compiler doesn't know who the *queen* in `button1_Click` refers to.

I believe you intend to use the *queen* you created in the constructor? Perhaps you should make that *queen* a property of the form then, or keep the reference somewhere else?

Comment: I did intend to use the queen I constructed in Form 1.  What is the best way to make queen a property of the Form?  And where else would you advise storing the reference?  Encapsulation, abstraction, all other good OOD principles in mind?

Answer (score 0):

```
Queen queen; // class variable
```

and inside your public Form1()

```
queen = new Queen(workers);
```

Comment: When I put Queen queen = new Queen(workers) inside public Form1(), just under the class signature, I get the error:  The name 'workers' does not exist in the current context.  Then if I take Worker[] workers = new Worker[4]; and all the other instantiated Workers[i] and put them inside my public Form1(), I get tons of errors:  A namespace cant directly contain fields or methods, Expected class, delegate, interface, or struct.   How do I make an instance of Queen have scope across my partial class Form1() so that I can access it in all the button clicks, etc??

Comment: If I keep the Queen queen = new Queen(workers) in Public Form1() and then add Queen queen; just before the button_1Click() method, it compiles without errors but fails when I run it due to a "Form1.queen is never assigned to, and will always have it's default null value"  What am I not seeing?

Comment: This is the specific line of code where I'm getting the NullReferenceException in the button1_Click method:              if (queen.AssignWork(workerBeeJob.Text, (int)shifts.Value) == false)

Comment: I would do as my code, but you also need to do it for "workers". Not only define workers, but also use new-keyword, to make space in memory. If you don't you will get null reference error